# How to extend AdonisJS Response class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

When a user creates a post in my RESTful application, I want to set the response status code to 201.

I followed the [documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/extending-adonisjs#_adding_macrosgetters) and created `start/hooks.js` as follows:

```
'use strict'                                                                                                                      

const { hooks } = require('@adonisjs/ignitor')                                                                                                   

hooks.after.httpServer(() => {                                                                                                                   
  const Response = use('Adonis/Src/Response')                                                                                                    

  Response.macro('sendStatus', (status) => {                                                                                                     
    this.status(status).send(status)                                                                                                             
  })                                                                                                                                             
})
```

Now in my PostController.js, I have this:

```
 async store( {request, response, auth} ) {
   const user = await auth.current.user
   response.sendStatus(201)
 }
```

But I am getting 500 HTTP code at this endpoint.
What am I doing wrong?

I noticed when I run `Response.hasMacro('sendStatus')` I get **false**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact adonis already have this out of the box for all response codes...

Just write response.created(.....).

You can also use for example: .badRequest(), .notFound(), etc...
More info on: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/response#_descriptive_methods

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem [yesterday](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/extending-response-class/3042/5):

```
hooks.after.httpServer(() => {                                                                                                                   
  const Response = use('Adonis/Src/Response')                                                                                                    
  Response.macro('sendStatus', function (status) => {                                                                                                     
    this.status(status).send(status)                                                                                                             
  })                                                                                                                                             
})
```

Comment: Check my answer... This is not needed at all. You are adding hook that is not needed.

Comment: I am sorry I did not check the link you shared. I de-accept my answer and accept yours. Thank you